Creating a dictionary from a subset of a list
Suppose I have python list like this:
master_list = ['a_1', 'b_4', 'd_2', 'c_3', 
              'a_2', 'c_1', 'd_4', 'b_3', 
              'd_3', 'c_2', 'a_4', 'b_1', 
              'c_4', 'a_3', 'b_1', 'd_1']

Each item in the list is a letter, underscore, and number. I want a dictionary to group this items by number in a list like this:
 my_dict = {'1': [], '2': [], '3': [], '4':[]}

While I could use the following to populated my lists inside my_dict, it seems awkward. Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?
for item in master_list:
    if '_1' in item:
        my_dict['1'].append(item)
    elif '_2' in item:
        my_dict['2'].append(item)
    elif '_3' in item:
        my_dict['3'].append(item)
    elif '_4' in item:
        my_dict['4'].append(item)


Understanding and using correct terminology will help you effectively communicate with others and vastly improve the quality of your search results. Here, you aren't creating a nested list - just a simple dictionary. And we don't talk about dictionaries as being sorted or not as they're an unordered data type (with the unusual exception of insertion order mattering a very small % of the time).

@Woodford - I have amended my question and title based on your comments. Appreciate it if you'd give me my point back. There are some good answers here.

You can use the builtin split function to split the input items on _ character.
sortd_dict = {}
def add_in_dict(k, v):
    if k not in d:
        sortd_dict[k] = [v]
    else:
        sortd_dict[k].append(v)

for item in master_list:
    add_in_dict(item.split("_")[-1], item)


All these answers worked, but this solution and the function that broke it down by k, v seemed to work best when I integrated into my code. Thanks all for taking a look.

with groupby
from itertools import groupby

sort_func = lambda x: x[2]
master_list = sorted(master_list, key=sort_func)
res = {key: list(group) for (key, group) in groupby(master_list, key=sort_func)}
print(res)


Split-off the index & use it to append to the right list:
sortd_dict[item.split('_')[1]].append(item)

